# Inventory Stock PHP Conversion [Magento]

Tags: php, magento, inventory, stock

I'll get straight to the point. What is going on here, is I have a webstore, that has an inventory system sync'ed up with it. The issue at hand, is that we get backordered a lot, or have preorders. In the system, it will go to zero or negative numbers all the time, but we still want them to be able to order them.. just not necessarily see that we are -100 of such and such an item.

I currently have;

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <?= (int)  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?> <span><?php echo $this->__('in stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability: ') ?> <span><?    php echo $this->__('Call for Availability') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This currently will show the inventory at whatever number it is, be it plus, minus, or at zero, which makes sense since there is no conversion to send it to out of stock if the number is =< 0. I am just not sure how I would go about mocking that up. So I come to you geniuses! Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You mean you can't get the Negative quantity of product stock , It just displaying the quantity only, Right ..? For example If stock is -5, but you got "5" only..

Comment: Currently if it was -630 in backorder, it would show 'Availability: -630 in stock' rather than 'Availability: Call for Availability' like I would like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Configuration => Catalog => Inventory:
Display Out of Stock Products => Yes
Manage Stock => No
```

This should allow to sell products without managing remained products in stocks

Otherwise just replace with

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> 
    <span>
    <?php 
    $qty = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    if ($qty<=0){echo $this->__('Call for Availability');}
    else {echo $qty;} ?>
    </span>
</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?    php echo $this->__('Call for Availability') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Those are the settings I currently have. It does allow you to still Add the product to the Cart if it is out of stock which is exactly what I want. What I am trying to do here is just show "Call for Availability" if the number is zero or below when the sync updates the current inventory stock.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far P0ZiTR0N! When replacing the Mage text with what you put, it ended up giving me this on the product page for an item with -630 backorder; "Availability: -630Call for Availability in stock", I figured atleast an easy fix for the initial number showing would have been remove the (int) prior to the Mage... but that didn't work. lol

Comment: Have you replaced all data or just one string?